# why does my principled bsdf shader look like this as in why does it have subtitles on it

Tags: shader-nodes

[image]

this is what i mean
how can i make the little subtitles go away

Comment: What you call "subtitles" are categories which you can expand by clicking on the arrows to the left. They are new in Blender 4.0 to make the quite long _Principled BSDF_ node shorter, because to the already long older version some features have been added which makes it even longer and so the not so basic settings can be reduced by showing them only if needed. Also the categories help separating the different options to make a bit clear to which main setting they apply. You cannot make them "go away", just like you could not remove the old features before they were combined under categories.